# appendChild in NodeList.forEach only appends the first element from readableStream

Tags: javascript, dom, fetch, appendchild

I have a variable amount of HTML elements being sent from my backend to my page where I want to then append the elements to the DOM once they are received (rather than all at once) as a kind of status update feature.

However, when I loop through the NodeList of elements received with either a for loop or forEach, appendChild only ever appends the first Node in the list, without iterating past the first loop. Is there a behaviour of this function I'm unaware of that causes this?

Removing the appendChild line has the forEach loop iterating fully, but with it in it only ever iterates once. I have inserted debugging lines that show it stops iterating after the first loop (console.log(i), etc.)

```js
fetch(`http://localhost:8081/${focussed.textContent}`)
            .then(res => {
                var reader = res.body.getReader();
                function read() {
                    return reader.read().then(({value, done}) => {
                        if (done) {
                            console.log('done');
                            return;
                        }

                        let string = new TextDecoder("utf-8").decode(value);
                        let elements = htmlToElements(string);

                        let root = document.getElementById("root");

                        elements.forEach(child => {
                            root.appendChild(child);
                        })


                        read();
                    });
                };
                read();
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.log(err);
            });
    }
}, false);

function htmlToElements(html) {
    let template = document.createElement('template');
    template.innerHTML = html;
    return template.content.childNodes;
}
```

I expect all children to be appended within the loop and am confused as to why appendChild only appends the first element in the NodeList

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you append a child to `root`, it has to be removed from `elements`, since a node can only be in one place in the DOM at a time. Modifying the `NodeList` that you're iterating over with `forEach()` causes it to skip elements, because when you remove something all the indexes shift down.

You should have `htmlToElements` return an array instead of a `NodeList`.

```
function htmlToElements(html) {
    let template = document.createElement('template');
    template.innerHTML = html;
    return Array.from(template.content.childNodes);
}
```